# Swift Stopwatch App crashing, don't know where I'm going wrong

Tags: ios, swift, crash, stopwatch

I am trying to make a stopwatch app for a coding class I am taking.  I have no errors before I run the code, but once I run it it crashes after "build succeeds".

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    var timer = NSTimer()

    var count = 0

    func updateTime() {

        count++

        timeLabel.text = "\(count)"

    }

    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func playButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("updateTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    }

    @IBAction func pauseButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    @IBAction func resetButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Here is the output console:

```
2015-07-23 12:52:26.877 Stop Watch[7472:467329] *** Terminating app 
due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:    
'[<Stop_Watch.ViewController   0x7ffdf1435b60> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key play.'

*** First throw call stack:
(
  0   CoreFoundation       0x000000010a814c65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
  1   libobjc.A.dylib      0x000000010c37fbb7 objc_exception_throw + 45
  2   CoreFoundation       0x000000010a8148a9 -[NSException raise] + 9
  3   Foundation           0x000000010ac32b53 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 259
  4   CoreFoundation       0x000000010a75cd50 -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 224
  5   UIKit                0x000000010b38b4eb -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1506
  6   UIKit                0x000000010b1e36d8 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 242
  7   UIKit                0x000000010b1e3cc8 -[UIViewController loadView] + 109
  8   UIKit                0x000000010b1e3f39 -[UIViewController loadViewIfRequired] + 75
  9   UIKit                0x000000010b1e43ce -[UIViewController view] + 27
  10  UIKit                0x000000010b0ff289 -[UIWindow addRootViewControllerViewIfPossible] + 58
  11  UIKit                0x000000010b0ff64f -[UIWindow _setHidden:forced:] + 247
  12  UIKit                0x000000010b10bde1 -[UIWindow makeKeyAndVisible] + 42
  13  UIKit                0x000000010b0af417 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForMainScene:transitionContext:] + 2732
  14  UIKit                0x000000010b0b219e -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1349
  15  UIKit                0x000000010b0b1095 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 179
  16  FrontBoardServices   0x000000010de7c5e5 __31-[FBSSerialQueue performAsync:]_block_invoke_2 + 21
  17  CoreFoundation       0x000000010a74841c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
  18  CoreFoundation       0x000000010a73e165 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 341
  19  CoreFoundation       0x000000010a73df25 __CFRunLoopRun + 2389
  20  CoreFoundation       0x000000010a73d366 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 470
  21  UIKit                0x000000010b0b0b02 -[UIApplication _run] + 413
  22  UIKit                0x000000010b0b38c0 UIApplicationMain + 1282
  23  Stop Watch           0x000000010a618fa7 main + 135
  24  libdyld.dylib        0x000000010cab5145 start + 1
  25  ???                  0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Can you add the crash log or the stack trace from the console to your question? Or at least tell us what it's doing when it crashes? Without seeing the other info and because you said once you run it, it crashes, my first guess would be that you have an outlet missing a connection somewhere which is causing it to crash due to accessing a `nil` value, but without seeing more it's just a guess. I would check all of your connections and if that doesn't work post your stack trace here.

Comment: From the crash log it seems that you have a connection to an action called "play", which is not implemented in code. Perhaps you renamed "play" to "playButton" without updating your connections? – As @pbush25 said, double check all connections in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the console log, I am pretty sure the crash occurs because of a missing outlet connection.

Press Cmd+Shift+F and type 'play' in the search field.
Look for a entry in your storyboard file, of the form `...: Outlet = "play"`.

Click on that entry and remove it by clicking on the 'x' button next to `play`.

This should fix the crash.

Whenever you see an error of the form:
`... this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key ...`
you should check if there is a missing outlet in your storyboard or xib.

Comment: This fixed it! Thank you. I'm new to coding outside of web development and am just learning.